# Probability: order matters

Tags: probability

A Senate committee consists of 5 Republicans, 6 Democrats, and 2 Independents. A subcommittee of 3 members is randomly chosen. What is the probability that the subcommittee consists of 1 Republican, 1 Democrat, and 1 Independent?

Why is the answer not (5/13)*(6/12)*(2/11)? What's wrong with the intuition of multiplying the probabilities of selecting one from each party? How does "order" play into this?

Comment: How does your calculation allow there there be, say, $3$ Republicans (which is of course possible)?

Comment: Because you described one of six possible ways to perform required selection. Probability for a first selection to be Independent, for example, is $2 \over 13$

Comment: From where did you get that the answer isn't what you've given? The order doesn't play into this

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim The correct answer multiplies this by 3!. This answer assumes that you first picked the R, then D, then I, however this could have happened in any order. Thus, there are 3! ways to arrange the items.

Comment: Two close votes, but I don't see why. The question is clear and the OP describes his approach to solve the question. Even if this approach is wrong, this question is perfectly  on topic on this site.

Comment: Another way to say it: the denominator $(13)(12)(11)$ counts (all) ordered committees, the numerator $(5)(6)(2)$ counts (favorable) unordered committees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pick apart your answer piece by piece.  Where does the $\frac{5}{13}$ come from?  That's just the probability of randomly choosing a republican from the committee - no mystery there.

What does the $\frac{6}{12}$ mean?  It isn't the probability of randomly choosing a democrat from the committee - that would be $\frac{6}{13}$ for the same reason as above.  Instead, it's the probability of randomly choosing a democrat from the committee *given that a non-democrat has already been chosen*.  That's where the ordering comes in - $\frac{6}{12}$ is only the correct probability if we are picking the democrat second, after a republican or independent was chosen and removed from the pool of possible choices.

It's the same for $\frac{2}{11}$.  This isn't the probability of randomly choosing an independent; it's the probability of randomly choosing an independent given that two non-independents have already been chosen.  So you calculated the probability of the event $(R, D, I)$.  There are five other orders in which the candidates could have been chosen, each with the same probability, so the correct answer is your answer times $6$.